# Google map api Android crashes

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2

I followed this tutorial https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start  step by step and this is my code. As soon as I run the code ,emulator  crashes
Here is my code

AndroidManifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.cics530searsprice"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <permission
        android:name="com.example.cics530searsprice.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.cics530searsprice.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
   <uses-permission                    `     android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.cics530searsprice.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter> 
        </activity>
       <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="I PUT MY KEY HERE!!!"/>
      </application>
    </manifest>
```

My XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" >
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/price"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Advanced search " />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:text=""
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/http"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="136dp"
    android:text="please wait--- price of the product Loading" />
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Ratings"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stepSize="3" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/location"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Search Location" />
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/shoppingprice"
    android:layout_width="326dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Shopping Price" 
    android:visibility="invisible"
    />
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/exit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Close" />
 <fragment xmlns:android ="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>   
</LinearLayout>
```

LOgcat:

```
03-08 01:20:13.478: D/AndroidRuntime(302): Shutting down VM
03-08 01:20:13.478: W/dalvikvm(302): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
03-08 01:20:13.509: E/AndroidRuntime(302): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-08 01:20:13.509: E/AndroidRuntime(302): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.cics530searsprice/com.example.cics530searsprice.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #67: Error inflating class fragment
03-08 01:20:13.509: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
03-08 01:20:13.509: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
03-08 01:20:13.509: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
03-08 01:20:13.509: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
03-08 01:20:13.509: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-08 01:20:13.509: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-08 01:20:13.509: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-08 01:20:13.509: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-08 01:20:13.509: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-08 01:20:13.509: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-08 01:20:13.509: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-08 01:20:13.509: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-08 01:20:13.509: E/AndroidRuntime(302): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #67: Error inflating class fragment
03-08 01:20:13.509: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:576)
03-08 01:20:13.509: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
03-08 01:20:13.509: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
03-08 01:20:13.509: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
03-08 01:20:13.509: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
03-08 01:20:13.509: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
03-08 01:20:13.509: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
03-08 01:20:13.509: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at com.example.cics530searsprice.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:79)
03-08 01:20:13.509: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-08 01:20:13.509: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
03-08 01:20:13.509: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  ... 11 more
03-08 01:20:13.509: E/AndroidRuntime(302): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.cics530searsprice-2.apk]
03-08 01:20:13.509: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
03-08 01:20:13.509: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
03-08 01:20:13.509: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
03-08 01:20:13.509: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:466)
03-08 01:20:13.509: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:544)
03-08 01:20:13.509: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
03-08 01:20:13.509: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
03-08 01:20:13.509: E/AndroidRuntime(302):  ... 20 more
```

Comment: can you put logs from logcat

Comment: Just added the logcat to the original post

Comment: Here is your problem. --> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader. Are you using SupportMapFragment or just the normal MapFragment?

Comment: I tried with both..same result

Answer (score 1):

i think You are extending `FragmentActivity`, indicating that you are trying to use the Android Support package backport of fragments. However, your  element refers to `MapFragment`, which is for the native `API Level 11` edition of fragments.

Replace `MapFragment` with `SupportMapFragment`, and that should clear up this specific crash

if that also doesnt solve Then you have a problem with your API key or something. Check LogCat for messages